# My scope variable is not getting updated if used through directive

Tags: angularjs

My home page includes bottom template (which has click event to open chat.html) and directive to insert chat.html code.

```
.....

<div ng-controller="BottomDockController">
  <!--include bottom dock partial template here-->
  <div ng-include="template.bottomdock"></div>
  <!--end of include bottom dock partial template here-->

  <!--include chat  directive  here-->
  <chat></chat>
  <!--end of include chat directive here-->
  ...

</div>
```

Chat directive code is:

```
angular.module("bottomDock.directive", [])
.directive("chat", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/partials/chat.html',
        link: function (scope, iElement, attrs) {
            $('#chat_selection_popup').hide();
            angular.element("#chat_close").bind("click", function() {
                $('#chat_selection_popup').hide();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

chat - controller

```
angular.module('chat.controller',[])
.controller('ChatController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.players = [];


           //**if remove below method along with ng-click event then I do get all players //
           $scope.showChatWindow = function () {
            $http.get("/api/players").
                success(function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $scope.players = data;
                    }
                });
        }

    }
]);
```

from inside template.bottomdock I am using

```
    <div ng-controller="ChatController">
        <div id="chat_icon" ng-click="showChatWindow()"><a><area shape="rect" coords="534,4,629,84" alt="chat"></a></div>
    </div>
```

chat html

```
 <div class="chat_modal" id="chat_selection_popup" ng-controller="ChatController">
            <div class="gm_user_box" ng-repeat="player in players">
                <div class="gm_user_box">
                <div class="gm_usr_heading">{{player.teamname}}</div>
                <div class="gm_usr_nm pvs">{{player.player_names}}</div>
                <a><div class="gm_usr_avatar">
                  <img src="images/avatar/{{player.avatar}}" alt=""/></div></a>
            </div>

 </div>
```

If I don't use onClick() event to load the data (through showChatWindow()), chat.html shows all players properly. But if I try to load it after the click event then $scope.players is not getting  updated. I tried $scope.apply which gives me an error.

I am not understanding why 2-way binding is not happening for $scope.player? Is it due to the directive?

Comment: But if I try to load it after click event then $scope.players is not getting updated.What do u meant by loading it after the click event?

Comment: it's not so good to use jquery inside your directive, maybe you should use a controller and template instead

Comment: You could add a scope to your directive: scope: { players: "="}. Then in your html add an attribute called players to your <chat> directive  to which you assign $scope.players (players="players")

Comment: @Divya MV What I meant is if I initialize $scope.players at the beginning  then I do get values for $scope.players. But if I try to initialize at later stage (after onclick) then I don't get $scope.players.

Comment: @muller  
Added  scope: {
                players: "="
            },  
Also added inside html 
<chat players></chat>
Could you please elaborate more on last part ? How & where I should assign $scope.players ?

Comment: <chat players="players">

Answer (score 0):

I believe its a proptype chaining issue due to the ng-repeat.You need to use it as an object as defined below.

chat - controller

```
        $scope.playersobj = {};

         $scope.showChatWindow = function () {
        $http.get("/api/players").
            success(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $scope.playersobj.players = data; //  or use this  $scope.playersobj = {"players":data};
                }
            });
```

chat html

```
     <div class="gm_user_box" ng-repeat="player in playersobj.players">
            <div class="gm_user_box">
            <div class="gm_usr_heading">{{player.teamname}}</div>
            <div class="gm_usr_nm pvs">{{player.player_names}}</div>
            <a><div class="gm_usr_avatar">
              <img src="images/avatar/{{player.avatar}}" alt=""/></div></a>
        </div>
```

Let me know if that resolves your issue!

Comment: I am still facing the same issue, if I initialize at the beginning then only I get values. I want to fetch values after click event and bind to existing one.